# Batch file not recognizing anything within an IF-ELSE statement

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm attempting to create a batch file that greatly simplifies the command prompt for people in the future, giving text-based menus for people to choose their options and place their needed arguments in rather than remembering this large command.

I've attempted to place it through a FOR, and fix whatever formatting I believe is correct, but it hasn't worked.

```
ECHO {{Are you certain you wish to run EarthShell.bat? (y/N)}}
SET /P confirm=""
FOR ..... DO (
    IF "%confirm%"=="y" (
        ECHO [[ STOPPED: EarthShell.bat encountered an EOF error, and needed to quit. ]]
        THEN ECHO [[ Press any key to exit... ]]
        THEN TIMEOUT /T 600
        EXIT )
    IF "%confirm%"=="Y" (
        ECHO [[ STOPPED: EarthShell.bat encountered an EOF error, and needed to quit. ]]
        THEN ECHO [[ Press any key to exit... ]]
        THEN TIMEOUT /T 600
        EXIT )
    IF "%confirm%"=="N" (
        ECHO [[ Press any key to exit... ]]
        THEN TIMEOUT /T 600
        EXIT )
    IF "%confirm%"=="n"  (
        ECHO [[ Press any key to exit... ]]
        THEN TIMEOUT /T 600
        EXIT
    ) ELSE  (
        ECHO {{Invalid response. Assuming 'N' and exiting EarthShell.bat.}}
        EXIT
    )
)
```

The code above, since I haven't gotten to actually placing the commands in, however, exits without giving anything within the IF-ELSE statement being read. It should, in theory, when I type "y" or "Y", say `[[ STOPPED: EarthShell.bat encountered an EOF error, and needed to quit. ]]`, then prompt for a key press or wait for the 10 minute timeout to end, then exit.

Comment: What do you see when you do `echo %confirm%`?

Comment: do yourself a favor and use the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command. There is no `THEN` with  `if`.  The rest of your code so far looks good, so I assume an error with your `for` loop. Please show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really think that you should be making use of the `Choice` command. The example below uses it and greatly reduces the code:

```bat
@Echo Off
Choice /M "Are you certain you wish to run %~nx0"
If ErrorLevel 2 (Echo Press any key to exit...
    Timeout 6
    Exit /B)
Echo STOPPED: %~nx0 encountered an EOF error, and needed to quit.
Echo Press any key to exit...
Timeout 6
```

If you wish to still use the inferior `Set /P` command and option:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
ECHO {{Are you certain you wish to run %~nx0? (Y/N)}}
SET /P "confirm="
IF /I "%confirm%"=="y" (
    ECHO [[ STOPPED: %~nx0 encountered an EOF error, and needed to quit. ]]
    ECHO [[ Press any key to exit... ]]
    TIMEOUT 6
    EXIT /B
) ELSE (
    IF /I "%confirm%"=="n" (
        ECHO [[ Press any key to exit... ]]
        TIMEOUT 6
        EXIT /B
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO {{Invalid response. Assuming 'N' and exiting %~nx0.}}
        TIMEOUT 6
        EXIT
    )
)
```

You will notice that I have used `6` seconds for the purpose of these examples, because I saw no benfit in replicating a ten minute `Timeout`, you are of course free to leave it as `600` if required.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out when I get access to a Windows computer again. My main is Linux.

Comment: apologies for necroposting here, but i've hit my question limit and, technically speaking, my next question would be a duplicate of this -- attempting to use choice, it's not seeming to change ErrorLevel at all in a new script. using the command `choice /t 120 /d Y` and a custom message, ErrorLevel is always returning 0, which it shouldn't be doing unless it gets forcefully broken.

Comment: @EarthToAccess, could you please try to expand on that, a [mcve] posted to a third pary site perhaps, and a little supporting information. If it turns out to be relevant to this answer, and I can do so, I'll update this one as needed.